# Remove cookies on client side with PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies, browser

I've made a login portal from my site to automatically login in other site. It works perfect. However, when I logged out I cannot login back from my site anymore because the site does not remove the last session. So I only can login when I started a new session, and can't login again with the same session for the next session after logged out.

I've asked the other site, and they suggest me to remove the cookie which is stored on the client side. How is it possible to remove cookies on client side from other sites with PHP??

Thanks

Comment: you can remove cookie but not session cookie.

Comment: have you tried `session_destroy()`??

Answer (score 0):

setcookie ("TestCookie", "", time() - 3600);// set the time to minus to remove the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

to delete cookie set it's expiry time to past,

`setcookie ("TestCookie", "", time() - 3600);`

more see in PHP manual [cookie's manual](http://us.php.net/setcookie)
.